# Can we access NetSuite 'Script Parameters' from multiple UE scripts?

Tags: netsuite

I need to store a configuration setting, and access it from several different UE scripts (different records).

It looked like 'script parameters' were the ideal solution. I created a script parameter on a script deployment,  and it appeared in Setup / Company /General Preferences.  The value I set there was then accessible to me in that UE script.

However I now need to use the same setting in several more scripts, on other records,  but it looks like I have to add a script parameter for each new script (with duplicates under Setup / Company).

Am I missing something here?  Is there any way to efficiently reference a single global setting from different UE scripts?

Thanks for any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the script parameter is a Company parameter, all scripts should be able to access it.  You just need to put the value in the Company Preferences screen and not the Script Deployment screen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do have the value on the Company Preferences screen,  and it reads perfectly in the script that I created it on.  But I tried it on a different script and it read back as null.  Have you seen a single parameter work on more than one script before?

Comment: Yes, I have used it multiple times and it always worked.

Comment: Great, thanks,  it must be some other issue,  will go back and look at it again.